# How to download a file with resume support?

Tags: go, download

Am using golang as a programming tool of choice.

What i wanted to write is a program that downloads large files with resume support utilising range requests in the http headers 
something similar to **aria2c**.

Comment: The current answer is useful if you know you're only going to use http for downloads. If you want to support a wider range of protocols, I'd suggest you to find a binding to libcurl - or something similar.

Comment: Going with libcurl is actually a good approach. in-fact i found a package https://github.com/go-av/curl which does pretty neat stuff written in Go-Lang and holds almost what i need as of Fetching the file.

Comment: [getparty](https://github.com/vbauerster/getparty) - may be what you are looking for. It is written in Go, utilising "het/http" package, and can partition download file. Resume also supported.

Comment: The [grab](https://github.com/cavaliercoder/grab) package supports automatic download resuming.

Answer (score 7):

To do that you should study the part 14.16 — `Content-Range` — of the [`RFC` document describing the `HTTP/1.1` protocol](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) and then apply that knowledge to manipulate the set of HTTP headers sent when the client request is executed — see the [documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) and examples there.

To calculate the range to request, to continue downloading, you should get the current file's size. This can be found in the results returned by the `Stat()` function which can be called on an opened file — `*os.File` returned by a call to `os.Open()`.

You should open your file in append mode and then use something like `io.Copy()` to stream the data from the `Body` HTTP response member to the file object.

Do your own research on how to read data from HTTP responses in Go — they are abundant on the Internet.